# stored procedure from hibernate3 to hibernate5 with cursor causes param mismatch issues

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, hibernate-mapping, spring-orm

I have legacy code that is using hibernate3 hibernateTemplate to execute a stored procedure using findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam with OUT parameter as a cursor. Below is what the hbm mapping looks like

```
<sql-query name="my_sql_procedure" callable="true">
    {call Schema.my_sql_procedure(?,:param1,:param2,:param3, :param4, :param5)}
  </sql-query>
```

Java code calling above procedure

```
List<?> errList = this.hibernateTemplate.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("my_sql_procedure", new String[] {
                    "param1", "param2", "param3", "param4", "param5" },
                    new Object[] { value1, value2, value3, value4,
                            value5});
```

Above code works fine with no issue in Hibernate3.

After updating it to Hibernate5. It throws below error.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Mixed parameter strategies - use just one of named, positional or JPA-ordinal strategy; nested exception is org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterRecognitionException: Mixed parameter strategies - use just one of named, positional or JPA-ordinal strategy
```

My guess is that Hibernate5 doesn't like that the first parameters (?) question mark is being passed as (?).

With minimal change to the stored procedure and Java code ( i have more than 50 stored proc all over the code) , how do I make above stored procedure execute properly using Hibernate5, so that it returns proper results with cursor as out parameter. I looked all over but couldn't find an example that used hibernate5.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam to execute a stored procedure that has cursor as out param.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do to make your existing code work. You will have to use either one or the other approach. Mixing parameter strategies is disallowed in Hibernate 5 for a good reason.

```
<sql-query name="my_sql_procedure" callable="true">
    {call Schema.my_sql_procedure(:param0,:param1,:param2,:param3, :param4, :param5)}
</sql-query>
```

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
    .createStoredProcedureQuery("my_sql_procedure")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
        "param0", Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
        "param1", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
        "param2", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
        "param3", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
        "param4", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
        "param5", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .setParameter("param1", value1)
    .setParameter("param2", value2)
    .setParameter("param3", value3)
    .setParameter("param4", value4)
    .setParameter("param5", value5);
 
query.execute();
 
Long commentCount = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue("param0");
```

Comment: what should the mapping and java code look like in hibernate5? If you put that here it will helpful for others as well.

Comment: There you go, I just replaced the first positional parameter with a named one.

Comment: java code that uses findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam?

Comment: I added the java code as well now but please note that you could have easily found how to do this online yourself.

Comment: I could find 50 different ways to call stored proc in java with hibernate but that is not what I am asking.  I wanted to find the solution with hibernate5.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam, so that I don't have to make much changes to my code. Any other option is too much change for me. Thank you for your help though.